# Is this code custom Queryable Mapping Extensions and if it was what the modern way to do the same code in another way?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

As my understanding to this code its map from IQueryable to Generic (<T>)
And need to know if there is easier way to do it.
The setup for this code is

Create a static class name  "Queryablemappingextensions"
and has this method

```
    public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TDestination>(this IQueryable source, params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand)
    {
       if (source == null)
       {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
       }

       return source.ProjectTo(MappingConfig.Instance.ConfigurationProvider, null,membersToExpand);
    }
```

and

```
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TDestination>(
            this IQueryable source,
            object parameters)
{
   if (source == null)
   {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
   }

   return source.ProjectTo<TDestination>(MappingConfig.Instance.ConfigurationProvider,parameters);
}
```

And I have the model "RoomType"

```
    public class RoomType
    {
        public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // One-to-many relationship: One RoomType has many Rooms
        public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have the service called "roomTypeService"
And has a method that get room type and retrieve a specific room type from the database for specific room type id

```
public async Task<T> GetRoomType<T>(int id)
{
 return await this._db.RoomTypes
                .Where(x => x.RoomTypeId == id)
                .ProjectTo<T>()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

And when I called the method it goes like this

`var roomType = await _roomTypeService.GetRoomType<RoomTypeViewModel>(id);`

The model RoomTypeViewModel exactly the same of the RoomType.

It seems that the generic mapped for the RoomTypeViewModel automatically.

Its working but I need to know how exactly it's work and if there any way to do this in another way that easier than that.

I tried the [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#queryable-extensions)
from the documentation and no mention about this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "easier" but as for what those two method do it is covered in the Queryable Extensions docs in the [explicit expansion](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion) section:

> In some scenarios, such as OData, a generic DTO is returned through an `IQueryable` controller action. Without explicit instructions, AutoMapper will expand all members in the result. To control which members are expanded during projection, set `ExplicitExpansion` in the configuration and then pass in the members you want to explicitly expand.

The provided code uses tactics of using extension methods with the same names and relying on compiler selecting correct method based on parameters (I assume the main goal is to skip the necessity to inject and pass AutoMapper's `IConfigurationProvider` in every place the `ProjectTo` is used via having a global instance).